# Log getting full while doing fast upload in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am creating a SSIS package that does a fast upload on the destination server. I am currently migrating around 2 billions of records. I am executing a query that is fetching the data and doing a conditional split into  tables based on ayear. I have noticed that the log is getting full. Is there a solution to this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could precede your dataflow with an EXECUTE SQL Task that sets your database's logging to "Simple".

Then after the dataflow, execute another SQL that sets the logging back to "Transactional".

Comment: Is FULL mode same as Transactional as originally the database is in FULL mode